# Aligned With vs Aligned On

Tags: prepositions

Please critique my sentences below.

1. Make sure we are aligned **on** this issue.
2. Make sure we are aligned **with** this issue.

I have heard people say "I am aligned" or I am aligned with this issue."

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

The correct usage would be to align **with people** (or other sources of opinion) **on topics**. Here are some good example sentences:

"Make sure we are aligned on this issue."
"Make sure you are aligned with us."
"Make sure we are aligned with the CEO on this issue."
"This aligns with corporate policy."

Comment: Understood. Thanks!